# How to change Notepad ++ cursor

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, cursor

I was playing around with a friend of mine and accidentally hit a bunch of keyboards on my Windows 7 laptop. I had Notepad ++ open at the time and when I came back to see what I was typing, the cursor had changed! Instead of being a blinking "I", it became a blinking blue underline, which I find very annoying. I have tried to change it in the settings menu as well as the styles menu, but I could not find anything relating to it. The text-editor pointer is still a blue-underline instead of a bar. I have the most up-to-date stable release of Notepad ++.

I could post a screen image if necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Press the Insert key on your keyboard. Try that first. Have you tried typing? When I have the blue underline, my Notepad++ is in OVR (overwrite) mode.

Comment: Yep, this is embarrassing for me to say, but it was indeed in overwrite mode. I could not figure out just to press insert, a nice feature I might say, to tell the writer about his/her current editing state. Anyway, thanks! When the ~10 minutes are up, I will put this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Just happened to me today. But I didn't press insert. There must be a combination of keyboard presses that point to "insert"; a combo in Notepad++ or MS; but don't know what that combo of key-presses would be.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> on your numpad. This only works if Num Lock is turned off.

Comment: The above only works if you are referring to the numeric keypad **and** numlock is off. If numlock is on then shift+0 (numeric keypad) will paste (and not toggle insert mode)

Comment: This worked for me when Insert failed.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

[04:50:48]  I am so in love with npp.

**Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> Carot Settings -> Width -> Block.**

Source:

Muimi@libera