# Microsoft Windows XP Underscore Cursor VS Black Rectangle Cursor

Tags: windows-xp

When in "typing mode" on my Windows XP, my underscore cursor somehow changed to a black rectangular shaped cursor, and has remained that way ever since.  How do I get the underscore cursor back?

Comment: What software are you talking about? Is it command prompt? Is it text editor? Normally underscore and black rectangle cursors indicate insert/replace mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Notepad ++ cursor](http://superuser.com/questions/747534/)

Answer (score 3):

Does typing overwrite the characters after it instead of moving them to the right?

If so, press <kbd>Insert</kbd> on your keyboard. You're in overtype mode.

Answer (score 0):

Push you "insert" keyboard key.
You're in replacement mode and not in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> on your keyboard.

There are two modes on a keybord which are "Insert" - where your cursor is a thin "I" and will place characters where the cursor is.

The second is "Overtype" where the cursor is a square and you will type over the top of whatever is inside that square.

Pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> will switch between modes.  Hope this helps.